# Turn a date represented as a string of milliseconds since UTC epoch to an actual date

Tags: javascript

I have seen a variety of threads that are adjacent to this topic. However, my google fu has failed me so far.

I have a value on my server that is a date represented as a string. I am certain it is the milliseconds since the UTC epoch.

I will write it like this for stackOverflow:

```
const k = '1638400203941'
Date.parse(k); // NaN
const a = parseInt(k, 10);
Date.parse(a); // NaN

// ah ha! but what about...
Date.parse(Date.now() - a); // nope, NaN
```

I am sure this has been done a thousand times before but how do I do this?

To clarify, the goal is to parse my server's output, `k = 1638400203941` into a date. YYYY-MM-DD or MM-DD-YYYY is ok.

edit: Somehow I didn't think to try the given solution. It was giving me `Invalid date` for some reason, guessing that I was passing in the string version instead of int. My mistake guys.

Comment: its `new Date(+k)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with you time in numerical format. I used `+` to convert the string to number.

```js
const k = '1638400203941'
console.log(new Date(+k));
```

Comment: For a more readable solution, you can write `new Date(parseInt('1638400203941'))`, so future programmers will know what's going on at a glance.

Comment: I prefer to use `+` over `parseInt` for direct numerical conversion. For better understanding I have mentioned the logic in the answer description.